# delete lucene index in ontotext graphdb

Tags: graphdb

I created an lucene index in ontotext graphdb based on [graphdb documentation](http://graphdb.ontotext.com/free/full-text-search.html).
However i cannot figure out how to delete the index with sparql.

Sparql to create index

```
PREFIX luc: <http://www.ontotext.com/owlim/lucene#>
 INSERT DATA {
 luc:analyzer luc:setParam "com.example.CustomAnalyzerFactory" .
 luc:index luc:setParam "uris".
 luc:moleculeSize luc:setParam "1".
 luc:myIndex luc:createIndex "true".
}
```

What options does `<http://www.ontotext.com/owlim/lucene#>` support to delete the index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to delete the index is to physically delete it from the file system. The index is located in `$GDB_HOME/data/repositories/<repositoryId>/storage/lucene/<indexId>`. After a database restart, all plugin information will disappear.

Please note that the plugin won't take any resources unless you refresh it! Having said this I highly recommend you to check the Lucene Connector, which supports automatic data synchronization with the database updates and deleting indexes:

http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/standard/lucene-graphdb-connector.html